# How does hibernate handle db updates by other processes?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a multiple processes running in C, C++, Java, JavaEE and the data can get updated in DB in any of these processes. So, if I introduce hibernate into the java process then how does it ensure that data being provided to application or being updated in DB is correctly merged with existing data.

Comment: By reading it from the database, which is the single point of truth. A correctly configured Hibernate app doesn't keep data in memory. It reads it from the database every time a new transaction starts.

Comment: How about objects in level 1 and level 2 cache of hibernate?

Comment: Level 1 cache is bound to the session, which shouldn't last longer than a transaction. Level 2 cache is off by default. You need to enable it and configure it correctly. Using a 2-level cache on data that is updated by external processes is simply not a wise thing to do in general.

Comment: I was really hoping to benefit from caching layer in hibernate but if "a correctly configured" hibernate doesn't keep data in memory then there is no point in me trying to replace SQL calls via JDBC with hibernate.